# How to use a REGEX pattern to remove a specific word "THE" only if at beginning of text string?

Tags: regex, strip

I have a text input field for titles of various things and to help minimize false negatives on search results(internal search is not the best), I need to have a REGEX pattern which looks at the first four characters of the input string and removes the word(and space after the word)  _the _ if it is there at the beginning only.

For example if we are talking about the names of bands, and someone enters *The Rolling Stones* , what i need is for the entry to say only *Rolling Stones*

Can a regex be used to automatically strip these 4characters?

Comment: Regex isn't your *only* option in this case. What language are you trying to do this in?

Comment: You need to provide a little context: what language are you using? On the Unix command line, the following command would do it: 

sed -i 's/^the *//' file.txt

Comment: Related, but not an answer:  If you're indexing band names or anything similar, create two fields.  One field is for the "display name" and one is for the "sortable" name, with the latter being used to determine ordering.  In other words "The Rolling Stones" would sort as "Rolling Stones" and "Peter Case" would sort as "Case, Peter".  Unilaterally chopping "The" off the beginning will break in an obvious way when you encounter "The The" and in a more subtle way when you encounter "The X" (which would cause a collision with "X").

Answer (score 3):

Applying the regex

```
^(?:\s*the\s*)?(.*)$
```

will match any string, and capture it in backreference no. 1, unless it starts with `the` (optionally surrounded by whitespace), in which case backref no. 1 will contain whatever follows.

You need to set the case-insensitive option in your regex engine for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `^` identifier to match a pattern at the beginning of a line, however for what you are using this for, it can be considered overkill.

A lot of languages support string manipulations, which is a more suitable choice. I can provide an example to demonstrate in Python,

```
>>> def func(n):
    n = n[4:len(n)] if n[0:4] == "The " else n  
    return n

>>> func("The Rolling Stones")
'Rolling Stones'
>>> func("They Might Be Giants")
'They Might Be Giants'
```

Answer (score 1):

As you don't clarify with language, here is a solution in Perl :

```
my $str = "The Rolling Stones";

$str =~ s/^the //i;

say $str; # Rolling Stones
```